# VBA Insert Formulas into Table Very Slow

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook that on open, turns the used cells into a table, and then injects different formulas into each column. I'm injecting the formulas to save file size from exploding by pre-dragging formulas down farther than needed. The VBA I have to do this works fine, but is incredibly slow. I've already run performance checks and can confirm that the slowness is caused by the formula injection (only 141 rows can be injected per second). I have already done the basic calculation/screen update related optimizations. What else can be done to speed up the following code? (Note I have reduced to the relevant portion of the code):

```
Sub OptimizeVBA(isOn As Boolean)
  Application.Calculation = IIf(isOn, xlCalculationManual, xlCalculationAutomatic)
  Application.EnableEvents = Not(isOn)
  Application.ScreenUpdating = Not(isOn)
  ' ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks = Not(isOn)
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    OptimizeVBA True

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Worksheets("Book1")
    Dim tbl As ListObject
    Set tbl = ws.ListObjects("Table1")

    tbl.ListColumns("Dollar Share ").DataBodyRange.Formula = "=IFERROR(([@[Dollar Share  ]] - MEDIAN([[Dollar Share  ]])) / STDEV.P([[Dollar Share  ]]), """")"
    tbl.ListColumns("Unit Share ").DataBodyRange.Formula = "=IFERROR(([@[Unit Share  ]] - MEDIAN([[Unit Share  ]])) / STDEV.P([[Unit Share  ]]), """")"
    tbl.ListColumns("Units PSPW ").DataBodyRange.Formula = "=IFERROR(([@[Units PSPW  ]] - MEDIAN([[Units PSPW  ]])) / STDEV.P([[Units PSPW  ]]), """")"
    tbl.ListColumns("Dollar Growth ").DataBodyRange.Formula = "=IFERROR(IF(OR([@[Dollar Growth  ]] = """", [@[Dollars, Yago]] < New_Item_Floor), """", ([@[Dollar Growth  ]] - MEDIAN([[Dollar Growth  ]])) / STDEV.P([[Dollar Growth  ]])), """")"
    tbl.ListColumns("Unit Growth ").DataBodyRange.Formula = "=IFERROR(IF(OR([@[Unit Growth  ]] = """", [@[Dollars, Yago]] < New_Item_Floor), """", ([@[Unit Growth  ]] - MEDIAN([[Unit Growth  ]])) / STDEV.P([[Unit Growth  ]])), """")"
    tbl.ListColumns("Comp Avg % ACV ").DataBodyRange.Formula = "=IFERROR(([@[Comp Avg % ACV  ]] - MEDIAN([[Comp Avg % ACV  ]])) / STDEV.P([[Comp Avg % ACV  ]]), """")"

    OptimizeVBA False
End Sub
```

I'm aware that selects/other interactions with Excel objects are expensive, but given that the above formulas are different, I couldn't figure out an easy way to reduce the separate interactions for each column.

Notes:

- There are actually more injections than shown above, with different formulas of roughly equal string length.
- On average `tbl` will have 16k rows.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Have you tried setting cell values directly? Maybe refer to whole Range, maybe fill one row and then autofill the rest?

Not sure, but it's possible that the table does some calculations behind the scenes despite xlCalculationManual? It may be worth a try.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I haven't tried setting cell values one at a time - I had generally read that would be slower. Re: the idea to fill the first row and then autofill the rest, are you able to share a snippet of how I could accomplish that? I would guess selecting the range is something like `tbl.ListRows(1).Range`, but how could I set each cell to the different formula and then autofill?

Comment: Not one at a time. One row at a time but direclty without reference to the table. Like this: `Range(A2:A200000).Value="test"`

Comment: if you set the first cell in a table to a formula all the rows of that table will also have that formula. that said, i am not sure this fits your exact need since you seem to be making the table on the fly after opening the table. however, what if you add the formulas, then make the table? just a thought....

Comment: @ScottHoltzman - I originally created the table first to avoid having complexity from identifying the cell ranges and referencing the columns by hardcoded column letters for the calculations, but if it turns out the table is the issue, that might be the way I have to go I guess

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One source of the slowness could be the use of the `MEDIAN` function --- it's more expensive/slow to calculate than `AVERAGE`.

In quick and dirty testing on my hardware using 16K rows of fake date and with Calculations, Events and ScreenUpdating all Enabled (no speedups), your formula

```
=IFERROR(([@[Dollar Share  ]] - MEDIAN([[Dollar Share  ]])) / STDEV.P([[Dollar Share  ]]), "")
```

took `5.4 seconds` to execute, but when `AVERAGE` is used instead of `MEDIAN`

```
=IFERROR(([@[Dollar Share  ]] - AVERAGE([[Dollar Share  ]])) / STDEV.P([[Dollar Share  ]]), "")
```

it ran in `0.8 seconds`, a speed-up of ~6.6X.

The problem is compounded by the fact that the same `MEDIAN` and `STDEV.P` get (wastefully) recalculated 16K times (once for each row of the table). It doesn't appear that the Excel calculation engine optimizes for this. You should be able to speed up your tables by calculating these values ONLY ONCE and then re-using.

One way to do this is to add a `Totals` row to the table and use `MEDIAN` as the total function. Then if your code is:

```
Sheet1.ListObjects("Table1").ListColumns("Dollar Share ").DataBodyRange.Formula = "=IFERROR(([@[Dollar Share  ]] - Table1[[#Totals],[Dollar Share  ]]) / STDEV.P([[Dollar Share  ]]), """")"
```

the run time gets reduced to `0.52 seconds`, a 10X improvement. You could also have helper cells on your worksheet to hold all of the `MEDIAN` and `STDEV.P` values; this should give an even greater speed-up.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Unfortunately I need median, but good to know the performance difference there. I'm looking into adding the totals row with VBA, but having some trouble figuring out how to use median - any ideas? `tbl.ListColumns(x).TotalsCalculation = CalcType` is the general pattern, with CalcType being an [xlTotalsCalculation option](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xltotalscalculation), but it just lists 9 as custom calc, without details on how to tell it the custom func.

Comment: Seems like this alternative more or less works:
```
    For Each col in tbl.ListColumns
        ' tbl.ListColumns(col).TotalsCalculation = CalcType
        tbl.ListColumns(col).Total.Formula = "=MEDIAN([" & col & "])"
    Next
```

Comment: I don't see a way to specify the custom calc via`ListObject` or `ListColumn`. One way to proceed is to get the row number of the `TotalsRow` using `ListObject(t).TotalsRowRange.Row` and the column number of each column using `ListObject(t).ListColumn(x).Column`, then apply the custom formula with `.Cells(r,c).Formua = ...`. Instead of using the `TotalsRow` you could do this in helper cells not linked to the table which would allow you to pre-calculate both the  median and StDev.p.

Comment: @ZaxR Good find!

Comment: This ended up getting me comparable gains to those you laid out above. Still having issues with other slow formulas that I'm having a harder time figuring out, like `.ListColumns("Unit Growth").DataBodyRange.Formula = "=IF([@[Unit Growth ]] = """", """", SUMPRODUCT(([[Unit Growth ]]>[@[Unit Growth ]])*([[Unit Growth ]]<>""""))+1)"`, if you have any thoughts about improvement there

Comment: Looks like SUMPRODUCT can become COUNTIFS in this case - testing...
`"=IF([@[Unit Growth ]] = """", """", COUNTIFS([[Unit Growth ]], ">"&[@[Unit Growth ]], [[Unit Growth ]], "<>""")+1)"`

Answer (score 2):

I'll provide you with my tests here, as this is too much code for comments.

I changed your code in order to paste formulas directly. I tested as strings (due to lack of your table setup) and it is basically immediate. So there must be some table-related shenanigans happening. Please try in your table. You will just need to adjust ranges/worksheet to your needs:

```vb
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    OptimizeVBA True

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ActiveSheet


    ws.Range("A2:A200000").Formula = "=IFERROR(([@[Dollar Share  ]] - MEDIAN([[Dollar Share  ]])) / STDEV.P([[Dollar Share  ]]), """")"
    ws.Range("B2:B200000").Formula = "=IFERROR(([@[Unit Share  ]] - MEDIAN([[Unit Share  ]])) / STDEV.P([[Unit Share  ]]), """")"
    ws.Range("C2:C200000").Formula = "=IFERROR(([@[Units PSPW  ]] - MEDIAN([[Units PSPW  ]])) / STDEV.P([[Units PSPW  ]]), """")"
    ws.Range("D2:D200000").Formula = "=IFERROR(IF(OR([@[Dollar Growth  ]] = """", [@[Dollars, Yago]] < New_Item_Floor), """", ([@[Dollar Growth  ]] - MEDIAN([[Dollar Growth  ]])) / STDEV.P([[Dollar Growth  ]])), """")"
    ws.Range("E2:E200000").Formula = "=IFERROR(IF(OR([@[Unit Growth  ]] = """", [@[Dollars, Yago]] < New_Item_Floor), """", ([@[Unit Growth  ]] - MEDIAN([[Unit Growth  ]])) / STDEV.P([[Unit Growth  ]])), """")"
    ws.Range("F2:F200000").Formula = "=IFERROR(([@[Comp Avg % ACV  ]] - MEDIAN([[Comp Avg % ACV  ]])) / STDEV.P([[Comp Avg % ACV  ]]), """")"

    OptimizeVBA False
End Sub
```

Your question from comments: how you could use autofill for such a task:

```vb
Sub autof()
    Cells(1, 1).Value = 1
    Cells(1, 2).Value = 2
    Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(1, 2)).AutoFill Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(10, 2)), xlFillCopy
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for this - I'll test shortly and report back

Comment: It appears the Table and/or the autfill itself might be the issue. Changing to `ws.Range("R8").Formula = "=IFERROR((AB8 - MEDIAN(AB8:AB16008)) / STDEV.P(AB8:AB16008), """")"` takes roughly the same amount of time as the original formula. Still testing... Note: The R and AB references are for the first row of formula setting

Comment: I looked into your table formulas. It looks like you're calculating MEDIAN and STD.DEV of whole columns for each table row. Maybe calculate them outside of the table and refer to those values? Not sure about how optimized such calculations are in Excel but I doubt they're great.

Comment: Changing to calculate each of MEDIAN and STD.DEV just once ended up making it take 1/10 the time. No luck with autofill (took the same amount of time basically)

Comment: Glad we could take it down at least by that amount. This must be the tables being slow in their calculations. To bring it down further consider not using tables. Formulas on cells are likely to be faster if that's an option.

Comment: Thanks for all your help on this. I upvoted this, but accepted another answer which, along with their comments, got me a little farther. It was a tough choice, though. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You can try to calculate dynamically the last row, if you ignore in advance its value, and so try to apply the formula to active cells and then autofill the formula to this last row of the specified column.

```
  Sub ExtendFormula()
  .
  .
  Dim Limit As Long 'Instead of Integer : Thanks to BigBen for it's recommendation
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False 
  Limit = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row 
  Range("B5").Formula = "=A5+2*B5" 
  Range("B5").AutoFill Destination:=Range("B5:B" & Limit)
  .
  .
  End Sub
```

Hope that can help you